# assembling lists with common central element

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm creating all the possible permutations composed of three elements from 0 to a given number using this:

```
for i in itertools.permutations(range(len(atoms)), 3):
    if i[0] < i[-1]:
        angles = list(i)
```

The condition avoids having (0, 1, 2) and (2, 1, 0) "angles" at the same time on my list, what is already great. Now, I need to separate this list into smaller groups being composed of "angles" which have the same central element. 
In this way I'd have:

```
A = ([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [3, 1, 4])...
B = ([0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4], [3, 2, 4])...
```

and so on.

Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby, permutations

perms = filter(lambda x: x[0] < x[-1], permutations(range(4), 3))
key = lambda x: x[1]  # sort and group by second element
angles = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(perms, key=key), key=key)]
# here, any comprehension can be used, e.g.
# angles = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(perms, key=key), key=key)}
# will produce the dict from @niemmi's answer

>>> angles
[
    [(1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (2, 0, 3)], 
    [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (2, 1, 3)], 
    [(0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)], 
    [(0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2), (1, 3, 2)]
]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this works great and is super fast to produce all the angles for big number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group the permutations:

```
from collections import defaultdict

angles = defaultdict(list)

for i in itertools.permutations(range(len(atoms)), 3):
    if i[0] < i[-1]:
        angles[i[1]].append(i)
```

If `len(atoms)` is 4 then you'd get following result:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
    0: [(1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (2, 0, 3)], 
    1: [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (2, 1, 3)], 
    2: [(0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)], 
    3: [(0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2), (1, 3, 2)]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `itertools.groupby` function can be used to create those lists containing the same central element, but you have to sort the list first so that permutations with the same central element are next to each other. To do that, you need to pass both `sort` and `groupby` a key function that looks at the central element. One way to do that is like this:

```
def keyfunc(s):
    return s[1]
```

or, as a lambda:

```
keyfunc = lambda s: s[1]
```

Or you can just use `itemgetter` from the `operator` module, which is succinct and significantly faster than using a `lambda` or `def` function.

The code below is based on your code but it creates the initial list in a list comprehension. Then it puts the groups in a dictionary, with the central element as the `dict` key.

```
from itertools import permutations, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

atoms = 'abcd'
perms = permutations(range(len(atoms)), 3)
angles = [list(u) for u in perms if u[0] < u[-1]]

keyfunc = itemgetter(1)

angles.sort(key=keyfunc)
print(angles)

groups = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(angles, keyfunc)}
print(groups)
```

**output**

```
[[1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 3], [2, 0, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 1], [0, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2]]
{0: [[1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 3], [2, 0, 3]], 1: [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3]], 2: [[0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], 3: [[0, 3, 1], [0, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the above answers provide excellent solutions to a more general problem, with just 3 element to choose a list comprehension is sufficient.

```
atoms = [0, 1, 2, 3]

angles = [[(a, b, c) for i, a in enumerate(atoms, start=1) if a != b
    for c in atoms[i:] if c != b] for b in atoms]


# [[(1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (2, 0, 3)],
#  [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (2, 1, 3)],
#  [(0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)],
#  [(0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2), (1, 3, 2)]]
```

It is also about 40% faster than permutations + groupby approach on my machine.